# How to iterate over a tuple in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

Let's say I have a procedure `getTuple(): (int, int, int)`. How do I iterate over the returned tuple? It doesn't look like `items` is defined for `tuple`, so I can't do `for i in getTuple()`.

I initially had this returning a `sequence`, which proved to be a bottleneck. Can I get this to work without affecting performance? I guess as a last resort I could unroll my loop, but is there any way around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I initially had this returning a sequence, which proved to be a bottleneck. Can I get this to work without affecting performance?

Use an `array[N, int]` instead, it has no indirection. Why was the seq not performant enough? You might want to allocate it to correct size with `newSeq[int](size)` initially.

Comment: My sequence was allocated correctly, but profiling showed lots of time spent calling `newSeq`. This was in the innermost loop of some performance-critical simulation code. I just tested `array[N, int]` and it's vastly superior - Thanks!

Comment: Of course in an inner loop you wouldn't want to allocate seqs. Instead of copying the resulting array you could also pass in a pointer and write to the correct location directly.

Answer (score 10):

OK, I figured this out. You can iterate over the tuple's fields:

```
let t = (2,4,6)

for x in t.fields:
  echo(x)
```